# How to add a few pts to the length?

Tags: lengths

I'm trying to do this:

```
\setlength\parindent{\parindent + 6pt}
```

It is possible?

Comment: `\usepackage{calc}` or `\setlength\parindent{\dimexpr\parindent + 6pt}`.

Comment: or `\addtolength\parindent{6pt}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard way would be

```
\addtolength\parindent{6pt}
```

Although you can use infix expressions if you use the etex `\dimexpr` command so

```
\setlength\parindent{\dimexpr\parindent + 6pt}
```